# Using a javax.servlet.Filter with Compojure

Tags: servlets, openid, clojure, servlet-filters, compojure

I'm trying to build a simple web site using Clojure / Compojure and want to feed apply a servlet filter to the request / response (i.e. a standard javax.servlet.Filter instance).

e.g. if the current source code is:

```
(defroutes my-app
  (GET "/*"
    (html [:h1 "Hello Foo!!"]))
)
```

I would like to add a filter like this:

```
(defroutes my-app
  (GET "/*"
    (FILTER my-filter-name
      (html [:h1 "Hello Foo!!"])))
)
```

Where my-filter-name is some arbitrary instance of javax.servlet.Filter.

Any idea how to do this effectively and elegantly?

Comment: do you want to apply your filter to all routes or only some? In the first case it may be easier to put the filter above Ring/Compojure, at the Servlet level. In the second case you need to write (with reify or proxy) an adapter which turn a filter into a middleware.

Comment: Thanks very helpful. I'd like to do the second but it doesn't seem to be possible because the request / response parameters that the filter needs aren't passed as parameters to the middleware system.

I'm trying the first - will post an answer if I get it to work!

Comment: To do the second you also need to create objects that implement HttpServletRequest/Response on top of the request/reponse maps. Or to use existing implementation (eg http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) but I think it's simpler to implement them with reify than deal with a stateful mock object -- as Rich Hickey says "Those mock objects, they are mocking you"!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I've now got this working! Thanks cgrand for the pointers in the right direction!

My solution involved creating proxies for a filtered servlet and a filter chain. Code below for anyone interested.....

```
(def pass-through-filter 
  (proxy [javax.servlet.Filter] []
    (doFilter
      [request response #^javax.servlet.FilterChain filterchain]
      (do
        (.doFilter filterchain request response)))))

(defn filter-chain 
  [#^javax.servlet.Servlet servlet]
  (proxy [javax.servlet.FilterChain] []
    (doFilter
      [request response]
      (.service servlet request response))))

(defn filtered-servlet 
  [#^javax.servlet.Filter servlet-filter handler]
  (let [#^javax.servlet.Servlet base-servlet (servlet handler)
        the-filter-chain (filter-chain base-servlet)]
    (proxy [javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet] []
      (service
        [request response] 
        (.doFilter servlet-filter request response the-filter-chain))
      (init
        [config] 
        (.init base-servlet config)))))

(defroutes my-app
  (GET "/*"
    (html 
      [:h1 "Hello Foo!!"]))
  (ANY "*"
    [404 "Page not found"]))

(run-server {:port 80}
  "/*" (filtered-servlet pass-through-filter my-app))
```

Comment: You don't need to add your filter definition to web.xml file?