# How to use javax.servlet.Filter in ring-based web applications?

Tags: java, servlets, clojure

I'm using a third party library which is written in Java in my Clojure web applications.There is a complex and important Filter in the library and i wanna know how to bring it into my application gracefully.

Similar problem here : [Using a javax.servlet.Filter with Compojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806548/using-a-javax-servlet-filter-with-compojure). But i think the best way to do this is by  *web.xml* just like in Java:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MY-FILTER</filter-name>
        <filter-class>[CLASS]</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>[NAME]</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Ring doesn't use XML.  Why do you think that XML helps?

Comment: Servlet based application likes .xml but that's not the problem.What i need is to bring servlet into Clojure.