# Do Spring Boot applications have a provision of using rest handlers (REST APIs) written in Clojure?

Tags: spring-boot, clojure, ring, compojure-api

I have a Clojure based web application using Angular JS. All the REST APIs are written in Clojure using Compojure and Ring. Now we want to host our application on a AWS Fargate instance which is a Spring Boot application.

I have been looking for a way to use existing rest handler in Spring Boot application but no luck so far.

Is there a way to achieve this or any other suggestion that might help us shift the application?

Comment: you could make a spring controller with `deftype`, that would call your existing clojure code.. https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_java_annotation_support .

Comment: @leetwinski 
I am sorry, I don't really understand how can we use already written url mappings in clojure from spring controller as controller itself contains all url mappings. 

When a request will come to spring controller it will look for that particular api in the controller itself, so I am confused how can I redirect all http requests to use the rest handler that's written in clojure.

If you could provide a small example through templates, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify if by "existing rest handler" you mean to include your Compojure/Ring app inside another Spring boot app with that also has its own handlers? If so, depending on the routing logic, you could recreate the mappings in a Spring controller, and use interop to call Clojure from Java, as described in https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_calling_clojure_from_java

Comment: @DenisFuenzalida
Yes, by existing rest handler I mean Compojure/Ring app. We want to skip recreating mappings in a Spring Controller as there are a few hundreds APIs written in that app. So, we are looking for a way to reuse those APIs without rewriting them in a Spring controller.

Comment: If all the APIs on the Compojure/ring app are mapped to a few routes (eg. starting with `/api`), I guess one approach can be to configure a WebApplicationInitializer (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controllers ) and forward requests to those routes to a Clojure servlet or filter that bridges to the Compojure side. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818227/483566